# Why does Ethereum Wallet application delay its startup until fully synchronised?

Tags: mist, synchronization

When Ethereum Wallet is launched, it displays a splash screen with synchronisation progress and a link **Launch Application** to skip waiting for being fully synced:

[image: Ethereum Wallet startup screen]

What is the rationale here for keeping user from using the application by default?

Why does it require an action from user to proceed when not fully synced? Is there any risk or disadvantage to using the application when it has not been fully synced?

Comment: What you mean by `using` the application? If you meant `send`, `receive`, `vote` etc. the app is designed to communicate with your local blockchain; that is why it works like this.

Comment: Actually I don't know (can't even imagine), which is why I asked the question. I can skip the delay pressing "Launch Application". What then? If nothing, then why delay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can access your personal accounts, you can do no operations that require the blockchain. The blockchain needs to be in sync first.

### What can you do

- Unlock your Externally Owned Accounts, which are priv/pub keys like in Bitcoin and watch the amount there.
- Create new EOA's
- Watch your transaction history if you had one previously which is not very likely.
- Switch to testnet and wait for sync of the testnet, mine some test ether, and since it syncs more quickly you can pretty fast play around with anything you can't do on Mainnet.

### What you can't do

- Send some ether to another account
- Create a contract
- Call a contract

Comment: Just to make sure about "what you can't do" operations: does it mean these actions will fail, or will they be queued until blockchain is synchronised?

Comment: I did'nt try it but under the hood geth is used and geth would not queue it. To me it would make sense that also mist itself doesn't allow you then.

Comment: afaik, it would queue the transactions.

Comment: I doubt it does in sync mode